# AngularJS $http.post with body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, spring, cordova

I have an application with **Cordova** and **AngularJS**.

With Angular I send a value to my backend application (**Spring REST**). The method I use for this is **$http.post**.

---

**The problem**

When I try to send data to my server Spring won't set the values in my entity. Due to this I cannot save my new data.

---

**Angular code**

My AngularJS code is as follows:

```
httpService.createInBackend = function (url, data, callback, errorCallback) {
    http.post(url, data)
           .then(function (success) {
              callback(success);
           }, function (error) {
              errorCallback(error.data);
           });
};
```

I use the following parameters:

url: `http://<location>:<port>/<application>/<web_socket_url>`

data:

```
data: {
        {
        "incidentTypeId": 5,
        "priorityId": 1,
        "creationDate": 1449676871234,
        "userId": 1,
        "latitude": <some valid location>,
        "longitude": <some valid location>
        }
    },
    timeout: 4000
}
```

I use '**data**' and not '**params**', because I want to send data via the body. I got this to work with a PUT function, that does not differ much from this function.

---

**My REST controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public NewEmployee createIncident(@RequestBody NewEmployee employee) {

    return employee;
}
```

---

**My NewEmployee model**

```
private int employeeId;

private int priorityId;

private String information;

private Date creationDate;

private int userId;

private float longitude;

private float latitude;
```

---

**Angular result**

When using the console, I get the following result from this method:

*I send:*

```
{
     "employeeId":5,
     "priorityId":1,
     "creationDate":1449677250732,
     "userId":1,
     "information": "hello world!",
     "latitude":<some valid location>,
     "longitude":<some valid location>
}
```

*I recieve:*

```
{  
     employeeId: 0
     priorityId: 0
     creationDate: null
     userId: 0
     information: null
     latitude: 0
     longitude: 0   
}
```

---

**PostMan**

I tried the same thing with PostMan (**Google chrome plugin**) and that way my code works. Due to this I do think it is an issue with my AngularJS code.

---

**I have tried**

I have tried using the following AngularJS call:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    timeout: 4000
}).then(function (success) {
    callback(success);
}, function (error) {
    errorCallback(error);
});
```

Yet this did not change the result. Still only empty values.

---

**Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: What type of content-type is Spring REST expecting in request?

Comment: Default it must be json

Comment: I have Jackson in my Spring (via Maven) and I am using @enableWebMvc, so I can automatically deserialize Json.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated code**

After changing the $http.post:

```
httpService.createInBackend = function (url, data, callback, errorCallback) {
    http.post(url, data)
           .then(function (success) {
              callback(success);
           }, function (error) {
              errorCallback(error.data);
           });
};
```

to standard $http type of angular:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data
}).then(function (success) {
    callback(success);
}, function (error) {
    errorCallback(error);
});
```

The sending of my data in the body still did not work.

---

**Solution**

The problem with this standard way of the $http request is that it does not accept an object like:

```
data: {
        {
        "incidentTypeId": 5,
        "priorityId": 1,
        "creationDate": 1449676871234,
        "userId": 1,
        "latitude": <some valid location>,
        "longitude": <some valid location>
        }
    },
    timeout: 4000
}
```

I had to change this to:

```
var incidentInformation = {
    incidentTypeId: $scope.selectedIncident.id,
    priorityId: $scope.priorityId,
    information: $scope.information,
    creationDate: Date.now(),
     userId: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).id,
     latitude: location.latitude,
     longitude: location.longitude       
};
```

and add a new line:

```
incidentInformation = JSON.stringify(incidentInformation);
```

I could directly set this value as the data value: 
(the Timeout has to be done this way and can not be set in the data object)

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: url,
   data: incidentInformation,
   timeout: 4000
}).then(function (success) {
   callback(success);
}, function (error) {
   errorCallback(error);
});
```

With this changed code the backend now recieved the data correctly and my application is able to save the data.

*Thanks Yoogeeks for suggesting the standard method. Strange that AngularJS $http."some method" works different than the standard method.*

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried without shorthand version of $http?
I think your code will work if you use something like

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(function (success) {
  callback(success);
}, function (error) {
  errorCallback(error.data);
});
```

where

```
data = {
     "employeeId":5,
     "priorityId":1,
     "creationDate":1449677250732,
     "userId":1,
     "information": "hello world!",
     "latitude":<some valid location>,
     "longitude":<some valid location>
}
```

[Further reading...](http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: I have just tried this but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: And the following is the content of data?
`{ "employeeId":5,  "priorityId":1,  "creationDate":1449677250732,    "userId":1, "information": "hello world!",  "latitude":<some valid location>, "longitude":<some valid location>}`
Have you verified what you are receiving at back-end?